# JavaScript or HTML5 to display image as 3D Canvas

Tags: image, html, canvas

Is there any way to achieve this effect (3D CANVAS VIEW) for displaying an image within a website? 
[Click here to view the image effect](http://i49.tinypic.com/2cigydg.jpg)


Is there any JavaScript Library or maybe HTML5 Canvas solution or it can be done via PHP?

Thanks!

EDIT:

To be more explicit this is the effect I want to touch with the library I'm looking for: 
[Check this type of displaying the images](http://www.greatbigcanvas.com/view/dusk-charles-river-boston-ma,68963/) without making the images by myself. I just want to automate the process and just display simple images like the types in the website from the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with [three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/), a JavaScript 3D library which can be configured to output to canvas, WebGL or SVG. Download the library and look through the examples and you'll probably find something pretty close to what you want to do. Essentially, you need to create a cube and use an image as the material.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'll check as soon as possible and will answer!

Answer (score 0):

I did a very similar one but using Imagemagick.

http://imagemagick.org/